# Obtener la imagen de cada usuario

Tags: python, django

Buenas estoy desarrollando un aplicativo donde los usuarios pueden crear citas, y cada una de esas citas muestra comentarios donde va la foto del usuario que la ha creado, pero lo que pasa es que cuando dejo la vista basada en clases con su contexto por defecto no me muestra la imagen, y si hago un contexto donde pongo al usuario que esta en la sesion, las imagenes se ponen solo la de ese usuario, no se como llamar o poner la foto del usuario que creo el comentario.
esta es mi vista

```
class CommentarieListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'commentaries/commentarie.html'
    queryset = Commentarie.objects.all().order_by('-pk')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        context['profile'] = profile
        return context
```

Modelo commentarie

```
class Commentarie(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='commentaries/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=False,
                            blank=False, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

modelo profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar.png', upload_to='profiles/')
    biography = models.TextField(default='Citas en proceso')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Adjunta el código del modelo `Profile` y del modelo `Commentarie`. Por otra parte, las "citas" son el modelo `Comentarie`?

Comment: si pues cada cita tendra un comentario donde el usuario dira su experiencia

Comment: Si pero quieres mostrar la foto del usuario que creo el comentario o la foto de usuario que creo la cita?? Si es el de la cita, entonces adjunta el modelo de citas...

Comment: disculpa formule mal la pregunta y es la imagen del usuario que hizo el comentario

Comment: OK, acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar la imagen del usuario que creo el comentario, seria así en tu template:

```
{% for comentarie in object_list %}
    <a href="{{ comentarie.user.profile.avatar.url }}">...</a>
{% endfor %}
```

No es necesario modificar algo de la vista o algo así, pues el comentario y el usuario están relacionados, y a su ves, el usuario se relaciona con un perfil.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: si me funciono, la cantidad de codigo que tenia innecesario era muchisimo, muchas gracias

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)